# Greatest Common Divisor Semigroups

Tags: semigroups

I'm trying to find a proof that shows if $a$, $b$ are in the natural numbers, then the sum of the additive semigroups $\mathbb N a + \mathbb N b$ is a subset of $\mathbb N d$ where $d = \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: This is obvious since for all $n,m$ you have $$na+mb = d \left( n \frac{a}{d} + m \frac{b}{d} \right) \in d \Bbb{N}$$

Answer (score 0):

$d$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$.  So
\begin{align}
a & = jd \\
b & = kd
\end{align}
for some $j,k\in\mathbb N$.

So $ma+nb = mjd + nkd = (mj+nk)d \in d\mathbb N$.